# How do I properly bridge networking between Virtualbox and Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox

I've been trying to bridge for a while now, and I'm not sure what's going wrong.

In /etc/network/interfaces, I added the following:

```
auto br0  
iface br0 inet dhcp
   bridge_ports all
```

Then, when I try /etc/init.d/networking restart, I can no longer ping anything through eth0. What's going on? I'm not too savy on linux network configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to switch the TYPE of emulated network adapter. You're using a linux guest, after all!

Answer (score 0):

The older (pre v2.0) versions of VirtualBox used to include detailed configuration instructions for configuring the virtual networking. The recent builds automate the process, and the manual cofiguration instructions have been dropped.

You can still download the older versions to access the help files, or you may need to check with the VirtualBox forums to see if the instructions are available elsewhere.